# Is it good approach assigning associated data in to variable rather than calling the association again and again

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance

I have queries like

```
@client.orders.last
@client.orders.pluck(:order_date)
@client.orders.where(delivered?: true)
```

As above  `@client.orders` is repeated 3 times .So is it good approach to assign  `@client.orders` to another variable and use that variable.
example

```
client_orders = @client.orders
client_orders.last
client_orders.pluck(:order_date)
client_orders.where(delivered?: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `@client.orders` in those three different ways *within the same request*, then your first form will create an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object to represent that clause of your query each time. That object will then be used to generate the SQL for each query.

The second form means that the initial object won't be regenerated on each line, which will cut out the initial object generation to happen once instead of three times.

But frankly, any performance gain is likely to be small compared with the time taken in communicating with the database and retrieving the results of each query, so I'd be very surprised if there were any appreciable difference in a production environment.

In that case, I'd say go with whatever approach you think is going to make the code easier for you to maintain.

If you think performance *might* be a factor, then it'd be worth using something like [benchmark-ips](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips) to compare your two approaches in your own environmental conditions.

Comment: You could also say that the code is extremely wasteful since it does 2 SQL queries without using the results in any way.

Comment: `@client.orders` will always be the same object so there is no performance gain or loss. On the initial call this scope will be cached. e.g. `client_orders.__id__ == @client.orders.__id__`